# Where are my background images

Tags: modeling

Previously I used blender 2.79b to model simple things. I have project created in 2.79b with background images. I put much effort to scale, rotate, position them in 2.79b.

I want to start using blender 2.8 but I came across weird issues. In blender 2.8 my background images are gone.  What should I change/set to have them back?

Comment: Object mode>Add>Image.

Comment: @FFeller I don't want to add new background image. I want my background image that I set in 2.79 to be visible in 2.8